# Strange 'indexing' of local variable: Fortran to C translation

Tags: c, fortran

I got stuck with a project that involves refactoring a code base originally written in Fortran.  The goal is to translate to C first then rearrange the code, then optimize it for parallel computing.

**PLEASE NOTE**:  I did not choose either the objective or the approach for this progject.   I was just tapped for the grunt work.  So please don't start hammering me with information about how Fortran can be parallelized, the comparative performance of Fortran in comparison with C, parallelism available in Fortran, or auto-translators.  If you can help, please just help with my specific question, if you can.  Thanks!

I don't have any experience in developing Fortran.  All I know about it, I have learned while translating it.  I ran into a strange problem where a variable declared as an integer is being indexed as if it were an array.

```
subroutine some_function(p0, p1)
integer local, result;
...
result=local(p0,p1)
...
return
end
```

What is going on here?  The local variable isn't even initialized with a value before this happens.  I am very confused!

Comment: Is there a `dimension` statement in the `...`?

Comment: That is probably a function call, not indexing....

Comment: `local` is a function returning `integer`, not a variable. Function declarations in Fortran (at least in F77) just specify the function name and the return type, and look for all the world like regular variable declarations.

Comment: could be a function or an array, I would expect either a dimension statement (array) or an external declaration (function).

Comment: Bah... it was a a function call.  Thanks for the head's up!  You should have posted this as an answer so I could mark it solved.